# How to put the big statement in one line

Tags: lightning-web-components, html, ui

Hi I need to put the two big statement in one line as shown in the below, can some one help me out for this

below is the screenshot

[image]

when i am putting it in one line then i am getting below overlapping issue ....can someone help me out in order to put the left word in one single line without overlapping on zooming.

Below is the screenshot i am facing for the issue.

[image]

Zooming at 125 percent left and right words are getting overlapped with each other.

**code:**

```
<template if:false={test}>
                                            <dt class='slds-item_label slds-text-color_weak slds-var-p-bottom_x-small' title='tyrufhdff hgyhgffghg'>
                                                <div class='slds-truncate slds-cell-wrap slds-size_12-of-12'>
                                                    tyrufhdff hgyhgffghg</div>
                                            </dt>
                                            <dd class='slds-item_detail slds-var-p-bottom_x-small slds-var-p-left_xx-large'>
                                                <div class='slds-col slds-m-left_medium slds-truncate slds-size_7-of-7' title='ytughhffhg - hgfyfhgfhb'>
                                                    ytughhffhg - hgfyfhgfhb
                                                </div>
                                            </dd>
                                        </template>
```

Comment: TRy adding the <dl> tags around your <dt> and <dd> tags and also you can restructure using table <td> and <tr> that will give you more clear boundries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Lightning Design System provides a component blueprint dedicated to [horizontal description lists](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/description-list/#Horizontal).

For you code, you should use :

```
<dl class="slds-dl_horizontal">
    <dt class='slds-item_label slds-text-color_weak slds-var-p-bottom_x-small' title='tyrufhdff hgyhgffghg'>
            tyrufhdff hgyhgffghg sfsdfsdfdsfsdfsdf
    </dt>
    <dd class='slds-item_detail slds-var-p-bottom_x-small slds-var-p-left_xx-large'>
        ytughhffhg - hgfyfhgfhb
    </dd>
</dl>
```

With that code, the label size adjusts depending on the text size.